# Criar um link de download para path que esta no mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho a seguinte estrutura no banco de dados:

```
reuniaoId   escolaId    usuarioId   dataReuniao tituloReuniao   pathReuniao
7   14  1   2016-01-13  AEQEQ   uploads/reuniao/ata_2016_2418530_2HK73386F.pdf
```

Preciso criar uma pagina de download desses arquivos

Tenho o seguinte código html que retorna a tabela e na parte de download precisaria criar um link para ser baixado cada arquivo no "pathReuniao" do `<th>` "download"

```
<table> 
            <tr>
             <th> Data </th> 
             <th> Titulo </th>
             <th> Download </th>    
             <th> Remover </th>
            </tr>

            <?php
                while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_amigo )) 
                {
            ?>

            <tr> 
             <td> <?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime ($linha["dataReuniao"])) ?> </td>  
             <td> <?php echo utf8_encode($linha["tituloReuniao"]) ?> </td>
             <td> <?php echo utf8_encode($linha["pathReuniao"]) ?> </td>
             <td> <a title="Desativar" href="excluirReuniao.php?codigo=<?php echo $linha["reuniaoId"] ?>"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>
            </tr>

        <?php
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Primeiro, o pathReuniao está hospedado no apache? Se sim, basta concatenar um http://seuservidor/caminho no echo.

Comment: upload/reuniao está dentro da raíz(www, httpdoc, public_html...) do site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se os arquivos cujo *pathReuniao* aponta estão no apache, é relativamente simples criar um hiperlink:

```
 <td> <?php echo '<a href="http://seuservidor/'.utf8_encode($linha["pathReuniao"]).'">http://seuservidor/'.utf8_encode($linha["pathReuniao"]).'</a>'?> </td>
```

Comment: a principio estão no apache.. mas futuramente vai estar em um servidor web.. funcionaria desta forma também se eu apontar para o site?

Comment: exatamente, só muda o inicio e pode apontar para onde estiver.